# Does Log.x() take any CPU if USB debugging is unchecked?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I know that to speed up things and eliminate CPU waste when an application is released, I can simply export it with `proguard.cfg` containing:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

But... if, for the purpose of convenient minimization of the juggle between Debug and Release version (which always requires a full uninstall one one before installing the other), I want to always run the debug version, *without* being connected via USB and with `Settings => Applications => Development => USB debugging` *unchecked*, do any of the Log.v(), Log.i(), etc. get executed at all?

I can't really connect DDMS via USB to check this myself... so, thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will still write your log message to an internal log buffer.

And there's some apps on the Market that can show this buffer, one of them called Android System Info or something like that, AFAIR.

Comment: Thanks! That Android System Info application is eye-opening. I discovered in my phone logs from 2 years ago... This must be taking lots of space. Is there a way to empty that log file?

Answer (score 1):

According to the ProGuard manual (  http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/usage.html ):

> -assumenosideeffects class_specification
>
> Specifies methods that don't have any side effects (other than maybe returning a value). In the optimization step, ProGuard will then remove calls to such methods, if it can determine that the return values aren't used. Note that ProGuard will analyze your program code to find such methods automatically. It will not analyze library code, for which this option can thus be useful. For example, you could specify the method System.currentTimeMillis(), so that any idle calls to it will be removed. Note that ProGuard applies the option to the entire hierarchy of the specified methods. Only applicable when optimizing. In general, making assumptions can be dangerous; you can easily break the processed code. Only use this option if you know what you're doing!

So the calls to Log.v(), Log.i(), etc don't even exist in APK.

Comment: Thanks but my question was **not** regarding Proguard. My question was about exactly the opposite: **No** Proguard applied, **but** `USB debugging` is unchecked *and* USB cable disconnected. What happens then to Log.v(), Log.i(), etc?

Comment: The log is written. It's always written regardless the USB debugging status. You may install a logview application on the device (like this: https://market.android.com/details?id=ukzzang.android.app.logviewer ) and ensure the logging still happens. I believe there is a syslog daemon running under the hood.

Comment: Thanks plus two. Is there a way to empty that log file? (is it only one log file?)